# Select specific number of sub items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this collection of data that I made a query on it

```
Hotel_Id  | User_Id | Comment       | Date
1           1         Hello world     2020-1-1
1           2         Hello world     2020-1-1
1           3         Hello world     2020-1-1
1           4         Hello world     2020-1-1
1           5         Hello world     2020-1-1
2           1         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
2           2         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
2           3         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
2           4         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
2           5         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
```

I want to make my query like this:

```
Hotel_Id  | User_Id | Comment       | Date
1           1         Hello world     2020-1-1
1           2         Hello world     2020-1-1
1           3         Hello world     2020-1-1
2           1         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
2           2         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
2           3         Hello world 2   2020-1-1
```

Query:

```
SELECT r.Hotel_Id, r.User_Id, r.Comment, r.Date
FROM rating r
JOIN hotel h
ON r.Hotel_Id = h.Id
JOIN brand b
ON h.Brand_Id = b.Id
WHERE b.Id = 1
ORDER BY r.Hotel_Id, r.User_Id
```

There are multiple brands and each brand has collection of hotels and each hotel must have only three comment not all comments that it has in db 
what is the type of condition that I should put it to get this data 
thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a row number and then select the records having the row number upto 3.

**Query**

```
select `t`.`hotel_id`, `t`.`user_id`, `t`.`comment`, `t`.`date` from (
   select `hotel_id`, `user_id`, `comment`, `date`, ( 
       case `hotel_id` 
       when @curA
       then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
       else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `hotel_id` end
    ) as `rn`
    from `your_table_name`,
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') as `r`
    order by `hotel_id`, `user_id`
) as `t`
where `t`.`rn` <= 3;
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcc00d/1)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want three comments per hotel.  You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by hotel_id order by user_id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.user_id < any (select 1
                       from t t2
                       where t2.hotel_id = t.hotel_id and
                       order by t2.user_id 
                       limit 1 offset 3
                      );
```

The `any` is to handle hotels that have fewer than three comments.

Comment: @Ullas . . . Of course it does:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html.  MySQL has supported it for over two years and counting.

Comment: Ohhh... That's nice. Its a new knowledge for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks , I added my query above you can see it

Comment: select t.*
from (SELECT r.Hotel_Id, r.User_Id, r.Comment, r.Date AS CommentDate,
      row_number() over (partition BY r.Hotel_Id order by r.User_Id) as seqnum
      FROM rating r 
      JOIN hotel h 
      ON r.Hotel_Id = h.Id 
      JOIN brand b 
      ON h.Brand_Id = b.Id 
      WHERE b.Id = 1
      ORDER BY r.Hotel_Id, r.User_Id
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3                          It gives me syntax error, I'm working on phpMyAdmon